# How to retrieve an Select one type of entries which has other types of entries which toward it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I currentl have an EF code first migration project, where I have migrated the code

```
public class Owner
{
    [Required]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class House
{
    [Required]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("owner")]
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("resident")]
    public IEnumerable<Resident>? Resident { get; set; }
}

public class Resident
{
    [Required]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("renter_name")]
    public string RenterName { get; set; }
}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Each of these entities is created as a seperate table in my database, with their own dbcontext.

the problem now arrises when I using the dbcontext want to read all houses, and list their owner, and residents.

how do i go about that?

A house will alwyas have an owner, but not always a resident?

So how do i query this?

How do select

I tried something like

```
    return context.House
            .Include(x => x.Owner)
            .Include(x => x.Resident)
            .Where(x => x.Resident.Select(y => x.Id == x.Id));
```

but Where does not seem to be supported?

How do i return a list of all houses and their owner and residents?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTRzg.png

Comment: so what exactly are you trying to get? all houses? all houses that have at least one resident? something else?

Comment: I am trying to get all Houses and their owners and residents..

Answer (score 0):

You should get all the Houses with their respective Owners and Residents with your query without the `Where` clause:

```
return context.House
    .Include(x => x.Owner)
    .Include(x => x.Resident);
```

Depending on when do you want to run the query against the DB you might also add `.ToList()` after the last `Include`.